# PowerShell script run through Task Scheduler - Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Database'

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I have a PowerShell script called through Windows Task Scheduler:

```
param(
    $FileDirectory,
    $VerboseDirectory,
    $ServerInstance,
    $Database
)

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $Database -Query "EXEC spImportReturn @FileDirectory = '$FileDirectory'"   -verbose 4> $VerboseDirectory
```

I then call this PowerShell script from Windows Task Scheduler as follows:

```
Executable:  %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Add arguments (optional): -File "C:\ChrisDev\PowershellScripts\MainPrograms.ps1" -FileDirectory "C:\users\user1\DER\staging\returns\"  -VerboseDirectory "C:\Temp\DbAdmin\ImportDERReturn\ImportDErReturn.txt"   -ServerInstance LONSQL01\SQLEXPRESS   -Database "ReturnsDatabase"
```

However I am getting the following error:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Database'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
> At C:\ChrisDev\PowershellScripts\MainPrograms.ps1:57 char:57

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks ok to me.  You can use process monitor to see what command is actually running, filter "operation contains process".

Comment: Does the script work when you run it manually from within PowerShell?